# Как узнать на каком экране сейчас запущено приложение?

Tags: c#, windows, окно, монитор, хранитель-экрана

Есть screensaver, и при запуске он открывает две копии приложения на количество мониторов. Мне необходимо чтоб некоторые функции на одном из мониторов не выполнялись - дублируются.

Как узнать количество мониторов я знаю - `Screen.AllScreens`. Как узнать какой основной тоже `.Primary`. А вот как узнать на каком сейчас запущенна данная форма?

Есть идея, что искать по координатам окна в каждом мониторе, но может есть способ легче?

Comment: Мне кажется, что только через координаты это можно узнать. Но что делать будете если юзер будет двигать окно приложения через разные экраны?

Comment: Это screensaver он запущен на весь экран и при любой манипуляции мышкой или клавиатурой - программа закрывается.

Comment: Хотелось бы что-то простое.
Если форма/приложение запущенно на основном экране то делать, если нет то делать.
Если простой способ не найдется буду координатами искать.

Comment: Ну, если у вас WinForms, можете попробовать [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121600/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-my-net-windows-forms-program-is-running-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для WinForms сделал небольшой пример ([на основе поста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121600/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-my-net-windows-forms-program-is-running-on)) - форма определяет, на главном она экране или нет

```
class F : Form
{
    public F()
    {
        var bt = new Button();
        bt.Text = "press me";

        bt.Click += (sender, args) => {
            var screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
            var primary = Screen.PrimaryScreen;

            if (Screen.Equals(primary, screen)) bt.Text = "primary";
            else  bt.Text = "secondary";
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```